# Clear result of custom function in excel addin before or after closing file

Tags: javascript, excel, ms-office, office-addins, excel-addins

I have created a custom function in excel addin which displays the response of any API. I want to clear the values of response after closing the file

[image: as you can see the values in the sheet I wanted to clear the values after closing the file or sheet]

Please suggest to me something how can I clear the values after closing the file, or is there any method that indicates file is about to close ?

Comment: Why not do this on open, if a workbook is closed incorrectly then it will still show the unwanted values when next opened, this can be achieved with VBA: `Private Sub Workbook_Open()`

Comment: @5202456 when i send test cases to user so user is able to see values before calling function thats why i wanted to clear values after the closing file, so is this not possible in  using  javascript office api ?